# Do I need a localization framework for a small PWA in React?

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization

I'm working on a small web application in React and I want it to be in two languages. I've seen several localization libraries like `react-i18next` and `react-intl` but I'm hesitant to install something maybe too big for such a simple application. Is there a lightweight library to do simple localization or should I look into a more straightforward approach like a string replacing component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a small project you probably do not need it.

However, it would be a really good experience to write your own localization component, integrate it with `redux` and opensource it.
Also, there are some simplified versions already available so you can reuse it and/or contribute into.
Here is a simple [react-localization](https://github.com/stefalda/react-localization) implementation.

Comment: Since it is a small project I'm reluctant to use redux, I'm checking react-localization though, looks like a good solution.